# Footer pushed to the bottom, 100% height and equal size columns pure CSS

Tags: html, css, height, sticky-footer, css-tables

I am tried so many ways, no success after searching and working for three days.

Html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
            <div id="header"></div>
            <div id="container">
                <div id="containertable">
                    <div id="leftbar"></div>
                    <div id="contents"></div>
                    <div id="rightbar"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="footer"></div>
         </div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
html{
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
html,
body {
   margin:0 auto;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
   width: 1024px;
}
#wrapper {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
   background: blueviolet;
}
#header {
   background:#ff0;
   width: 1024px;
   height: 70px;
}
#container {
   padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   display: table;
}
#containertable{
    width: 1024px;
    display: table-row;
}
#leftbar, #rightbar{
    width: 170px;
    height: 100px;
    display: table-cell;
    background: brown;
}
#contents{
    width: 684px;
    height: 200px;
    display: table-cell;
    background: burlywood;
}
#footer {
   width: 1024px;
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6cf;
}
```

Using the above code and other versions, I am able to get the 1 and 2nd cases, But I am not able to make the columns stay 100% height and equal and push the footer to the bottom of the page.

In the below image, I am looking for the third case at all the situations.

[Three different cases of pushing the footer div to the bottom of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUVI0.png)

Comment: If it is just about applying a background to the columns, you could use pseudo elements and stretch those over the whole parent container. Something like in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LznnG/1/).

Comment: thank you so much Martin you saved my life. That was an awesome fix.. Is there any fix for IE7 and below. I had to support IE7 at least. Plz help me thanks in advance..

Comment: between, Why have you used so many z-index values, was there a reason behind it..??

Comment: @martinTurjak, hyperlinks and buttons are not working inside the divs

Comment: The quick example from before was mostly just to show you how you could use the `:before` pseudo element. I don't remember why I was playing with the z-indexes anymore if I am honest ... the overlapping elements will prevent the ones underneath from being clickable. Anyway here I cleaned it up for you a little: [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LznnG/3/). However, CSS3 stuff will not work in IE7, but you could just [**add some extra divs to the markup**](http://jsfiddle.net/LznnG/4/) that fulfill the same function as the pseudo elements, which will work in the obsolete browsers.

Comment: @MartinTurjak, You are great..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Martin Turjak gave the solution below and that worked great for me.

Jsfiddle

```
 http://jsfiddle.net/yellowandred/LznnG/5/
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="column1"><a href="#">Test</a></div>
    <div class="column2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
}
.wrapper {
    position:relative;
    min-height:100%;
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto;
    font-size:0px;
}
.wrapper div {
    font-size:16px;
}
.column1, .column2 {
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    height:100%;
    bottom:0;
}
.column1::before, .column2::before {
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    background:pink;
    right:0;
    z-index:-1;
}
.column1::before {
    background:green;
    left:0;
}
.column2::before {
    background:blue;
    left:30%;
}
.column1 {
    width:30%;
}
.column2 {
    width:70%;
}
.spacer {
    position:relative;
    clear:both;
}
.footer {
    position:absolute;
    height:30px;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    background:orange;
}
```